# docker container keeps restarting due to error in daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I am trying to use jProfiler in a docker container to listen the performance of my app.

I am trying to follow this guide: https://gist.github.com/Kevin-Lee/cbfbde89d68299304b1b1a2e6371fe06#visualvm-with-docker .

I should be able to connect to this container from outside via a browser. My app should be able to connect to it.

I have this docker file,

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
RUN wget https://download-gcdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux-x64_12_0_2.tar.gz -P /tmp/ && \
  tar -xzf /tmp/jprofiler_linux-x64_12_0_2.tar.gz -C /usr/local &&\
  rm /tmp/jprofiler_linux-x64_12_0_2.tar.gz

EXPOSE 7777
```

I have this docker-compose file

```
version: "3.6"

services:

    juju-jprofiler:
        container_name: "ng-j-profiler"
        build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        restart: "unless-stopped"
        network_mode: bridge
        ports:
          - "7777:7777"

volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  dhparam:
```

I am getting to create the container, but it keep restarting due to an error in the daemon.

[image]

My goal is to install a jProfiler inside a docker container.

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't have a `CMD`.  What's the container supposed to do once you start it up?

Comment: First of all you do not have any `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command. Second, what's the error? Edit the question and add it

Comment: @Saeed The ENTRYPOINT would be required in the docker file of my java app.